# How to troubleshoot "Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference to scala.ScalaObject encountered in class file 'package.class'"?

Tags: scala, sbt

I face this error message when I try to run the project:

```
Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference to scala.ScalaObject encountered in class file 'package.class'.
Cannot access type ScalaObject in package scala. The current classpath may be
missing a definition for scala.ScalaObject, or package.class may have been compiled against a version that's incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
```

There are similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24630595/1305344) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18045959/1305344), but none seems to be applicable to my case - mine isn't spitting out such messages. The only thing I have to go one is `scalaObject.`

This is a sudden breakage -- the project was made inside IntelliJ IDEA with sbt and ran find until today. Suddenly, it can't find what it needs.

This is the whole `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "MyApp"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "joda-time" % "joda-time"    % "2.3",
  "org.joda"  % "joda-convert" % "1.6",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.9.2",
```

How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Can you paste an output of the `about` command? Additionally are you sure this is the whole of your build file, because it seems like it's ending quite rapidly.

Comment: That can't be the whole build file: it wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have changed `sbt.version` in `project/build.properties` or `scalaVersion` in `build.sbt`. Or just `sbt` the launcher. Or the Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA. Could that be the case?

I'm basing it on *"or package.class may have been compiled against a version that's
incompatible with the one found on the current classpath."*.

You may want to see `update` reports in `target\resolution-cache\reports`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I am having a similar problem, and I don't see an 'update' file in `target\resolution-cache\reports`. Even removing all dependencies from my `build.sbt` file I am still getting a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are using IntelliJ IDEA. I am using the Scala IDE for Eclipse and I ran across this error. It only occurred when I turned off this option in the IDE config:

withVersionClasspathValidator - Check Scala compatibility of jars in classpath

When this option was turned on, I instead got:

mongo-casbah-commons_2.8.1-2.1.2.jar is cross-compiled with an incompatible version of Scala (2.8.1).

I'm new to Scala, but this seems to be because I'm using Scala 2.11.2 to compile, but I'm including a jar that was built using Scala 2.8.1.